# Return interface implementation with Kotlin and lambda

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I have this simple interface :

```
interface ValidationBehavior {
    fun onValidated()
}
```

This interface is used in one function of a class :

```
private enum class BehaviorEnum {
    IDLE,
    NAVIGATEBACK
}

private fun getBehavior(payloadBehavior: String) : ValidationBehavior {
    when(BehaviorEnum.valueOf(payloadBehavior)) {
        BehaviorEnum.IDLE -> return object: ValidationBehavior {
            override fun onValidated() {
                // do some stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is : is there a way to simplify the return statement with a lambda ? I try some stuff like this but it doesn't work :

```
return ValidationBehavior{ () -> //do some stuff }
```

**EDIT :**

Kotlin supports SAM interfaces now so declaring it like so :

```
fun interface ValidationBehavior {
    fun operator onValidated()
}
```

allows us to write :

```
return ValidationBehavior { //do some stuff }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, interfaces written in Kotlin cannot be instantiated with a lambda, that only works for interfaces written in Java. If you want to use lambdas in Kotlin, use the functional type, like in your case `() -> Unit` instead of `ValidationBehavior`.

Alternatively, write a method that takes a functional type and wraps it in a `ValidationBehavior`:

```
interface ValidationBehavior {

    companion object {
        inline operator fun invoke(fn: () -> Unit) = object: ValidationBehavior {
            override fun onValidated() = fn()
        }
    }

    fun onValidated()
}

private fun getBehavior(payloadBehavior: String) : ValidationBehavior {
    when(BehaviorEnum.valueOf(payloadBehavior)) {
        BehaviorEnum.IDLE -> return ValidationBehavior { /* do stuff */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be acceptable to create the interface in Java and use it in Kotlin ? In order to avoid to create the inline function and being able to use the interface directly  with lambdas

Comment: If you or your team find it okay, then I guess it would be ok. However consider just dropping the interface and using the functional type.

Comment: any use of java-interop for hacking kotlin is not-idiomatic, obviously. A factory function is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but there is a way to do it in Kotlin. Look at [fun interface kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#sam-conversions) there is a simple way to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I edited my post a few months ago saying exactly that.

Comment: Oh right, didn't see sorry